# Altering an image fields output in a View

Tags: 7, views

On our site, users are given the choice to make their profiles private or public. They also have the ability to upload a profile pic, and if they don't, there's a default placeholder image.

If a user who's profile is set to private creates a piece of content, and another user looks at that piece of content, a broken image is displayed (with a 403 forbidden error message). We are using the Views module to display the bits of data.

What is the best way to alter the View so that if the account is private, rather than serving up the broken image, it displays the placeholder?

Comment: are you using custom view template file to display the view?

Comment: How do you give your users the choice of making their profiles private or public?